# swift 2: How do I split a string without loosing the characters it split on?

Tags: regex, swift, split

Assuming I have the string `"a:b:c"` how do I split it so that I end up with the array `["a", ":", "b", ":", "c"]`?

My ultimate goal is method I can pass in a regexp for whatever delimiters I want (not just ":") but I can't figure out how to split a string in Swift 2 without loosing the characters it split on.

[edit] to clarify (based on comments) I'm not trying to split it by character, and I'm not trying to split on ":" specifically. It's just a random delimiter that I thought would provide a simple example. I want to know how to split a string on ANY random delimiter defined in a regexp and NOT loose the delimiter.   "fooBerry-BazClom*" split on something like `[B\\-*]` would get me `["foo", "B", "erry", "-", "B", "az", "Clom", "*"]`

Comment: split according to `(:)`

Comment: no... it's an arbitrary delimiter. and splitting on ":" would result in an array with no ":" in it. I need an array with whatever it was split on still in it.

Comment: Search for "How to split a string using a regular expression in Objective-C".  The approach will be exactly the same in Swift (i.e. use NSRegularExpression)

Comment: Could you try splitting on `(?=:)|(?<=:)`? I'm not sure how Swift will handle that, but I'd be interested in seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by putting a backreference in your template. It feels a little crude to me, but out of the proposed solutions it's the fastest by a long shot (see performance notes at the end of this)

```
let y="YupNope-FractalOrangexbluey";
let testPattern="(Nope|-|[xy])";

func splitStingOnRegex(aString: String, aPattern: String) -> Array<String> {
    do{
        let regEx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: aPattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
        let template = "\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}$1\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}"
        // u+1635 is an ancient rune unlikely to show up in modern text (or ancient (i hope)) 3 times in a row
        let modifiedString = regEx.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(
            aString, options: NSMatchingOptions(),
            range: NSMakeRange(0, aString.characters.count),
            withTemplate:template)
        let cleanedSideBySideMatches = modifiedString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}", withString: "\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

        let arrPlusOne = cleanedSideBySideMatches.componentsSeparatedByString("\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}")
        if arrPlusOne.count > 1 {
            return Array(arrPlusOne[0...(arrPlusOne.count - 2)]);
            // because there's always an extra one at the end
        } else {
            return arrPlusOne;
            // nothing was matched
        }
    } catch {
        return []
    }
}

splitStingOnRegex(y, aPattern: testPattern);
// ["Yup", "Nope", "-", "FractalOrange", "x", "blue", "y"]
```

Alternately you can get an array of the matches, and an array of the things that didn't match and zip them together.

```
func newSplitStringOnRegex(aString: String, aPattern: String) -> Array<String>{
    do {
        let regEx = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: aPattern, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions())
        let template = "\u{16E5}\u{16E5}\u{16E5}"
        let aNSString = aString as NSString;
        // u+1635 is an ancient rune unlikely to show up in modern text (or ancient (i hope)) 3 times in a row
        var modifiedString = regEx.stringByReplacingMatchesInString(
            aString, options: NSMatchingOptions(),
            range: NSMakeRange(0, aString.characters.count),
            withTemplate:template)
        // if the first match was at the beginning
        // we'll end up with an extra "" at the start of our array when we split
        if modifiedString.hasPrefix(template) {
            modifiedString = (modifiedString as NSString).substringFromIndex(3);
        }
        modifiedString

        let unmatchedItems = modifiedString.componentsSeparatedByString(template)
        unmatchedItems.last
        let matchRanges = regEx.matchesInString(aString, options: NSMatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, aString.characters.count));
        let matches = matchRanges.map { aNSString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
        // now let's zip the matched and unmatched items together
        let merged = zip(unmatchedItems, matches).map{[$0.0, $0.1]}.flatMap({$0});

        // zip will leave any extra items off the end
        // because this is ultimately a split we'll never have more than one extra
        if unmatchedItems.count > matches.count {
            return merged + [unmatchedItems.last!];
        } else if matches.count > unmatchedItems.count {
            return merged + [matches.last!];
        }
        // no extras
        return merged;

    } catch {
        return Array<String>();
    }
}

newSplitStringOnRegex(text, aPattern: testPattern);
// ["Yup", "Nope", "", "Nope", "FractalOrange", "-", "blue", "x", "", "y"]
```

### Performance notes

Testing these two, plus Alain T's on my computer with a test string that had ~50 matches and ~50 delimiters: I ran them each 1000 times and got these results:

- splitStingOnRegex (my first solution) ~7 seconds
- newSplitStringOnRegex (my second solution) ~ 32.5 seconds
- componentsFromRegExp (Alain's 2nd) ~ 152 seconds
- componentsStartingFromCharactersInSet (Alain's 1st) ~ 122 seconds

So there you have it. Crufty simple-minded solutions for the win. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick (not sure if it is very efficient though):

```
extension String
{
   func componentsStartingFromCharactersInSet(searchSet: NSCharacterSet) -> [String]
   {
      if self == "" { return [] }

      if let firstDelimiter = rangeOfCharacterFromSet(searchSet)         
      {
         let delimiter       = self.substringWithRange(firstDelimiter)
         var result:[String] = []

         if let rightIndex = firstDelimiter.last?.successor()
         { result = self.substringFromIndex(rightIndex).componentsStartingFromCharactersInSet(searchSet) }

         result.insert(delimiter, atIndex:0)

         if !hasPrefix(delimiter)
         { result.insert(self.substringToIndex(firstDelimiter.first!), atIndex:0) }

         return result
      }
      return [self]       
   }
}
```

Using it as follows :

```
let searchSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString:"B\\-*")
"fooBerry-BazClom*".componentsStartingFromCharactersInSet(searchSet)
```

returns ["foo", "B", "erry", "-", "B", "azClom", "*"]

Given that you need an regular expression to express the delimiters, I'm not certain what you're aiming for but here's a modified version based on regular expressions (and some fiddling with range type casting):

```
extension String
{   
   var length:Int {return (self as NSString).length }

   func stringRange(range:NSRange) -> Range<String.Index>
   {
     let start = self.startIndex.advancedBy(range.location) 
     let end   = start.advancedBy(range.length) 
     return Range<String.Index>(start: start, end: end)
   }

   func componentsFromRegExp(regExp:String) -> [String]
   {
     if self == "" { return [] }
     do
     {
        let expression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regExp, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)
        return self.componentsFromRegExp(expression) 
     }
     catch { return [self] }
   }

   func componentsFromRegExp(regExp:NSRegularExpression) -> [String]
   {
      if self == "" { return [] }

      if let firstMatch = regExp.firstMatchInString(self, options:NSMatchingOptions(rawValue:0), range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length) )
         where firstMatch.range.length > 0         
      {
         let firstDelimiter  = self.stringRange(firstMatch.range)
         let delimiter       = self.substringWithRange(firstDelimiter)
         var result:[String] = []

         if let rightIndex = firstDelimiter.last?.successor()
         { result = self.substringFromIndex(rightIndex).componentsFromRegExp(regExp) }

         result.insert(delimiter, atIndex:0)

         if !hasPrefix(delimiter)
         { result.insert(self.substringToIndex(firstDelimiter.first!), atIndex:0) }

         return result
      }
      return [self]       
   }
}
```

I had to use a different syntax in the regular expression to define the delimiters. That's why I'm not sure I fully understood what you need.

```
"fooBerry-BazClom*".componentsFromRegExp("B|-|\\*")
// returns ["foo", "B", "erry", "-", "B", "azClom", "*"]
```

Comment: a) thanks b) I wish i could give points for a half answer. So, that works IF your delimiter is a single character.  I'm looking for something that can split on "ANY random delimiter defined in a regexp" So `\\w+\\s{0,4}beetleju.*ice` could be the delimiter.

Comment: I did some performance testing on your solutions and mine and added the results to the bottom of my answer. The results were surprising (to me).